# Nuget project.json vs packages.config

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

Here is an error that I receive in a W10 Universal app.

> Warning       Could not locate C:\Users...\Examplinvi.UniversalApp\packages.config.
>   Ensure that this project has Microsoft.Bcl.Build installed and packages.config is located next to the project file. Examplinvi.UniversalApp

My app has a project.json (which is kind of the new packages.config). 
But I do not understand what this warning is trying to warn me for. 
I have also Microsoft.Bcl.Build installed and referenced by the project and the project.json.

Also, if I create a packages.config, I have new warnings coming in like :

> Warning       Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190. Examplinvi

Any idea to fix this warning?

Comment: A UWP app should not depend on such compatibility packages, so you should check how you got it into your project.

Comment: Well it uses a Portable Class Library.

Answer (score 0):

add this :

```
<SkipValidatePackageReferences>true</SkipValidatePackageReferences>
```

at the top of your csproj/vbproj. It should work. Worked for me.